# gtihub, jenkins and automated testing

Tags: testing, github, jenkins

I have several projects in Github, and I´d like to linked them to Jenkins in order to automate testing and improve the quality code.

Is there any free online way to do it?

Comment: do you mean you want to run tests on some cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [git jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) allows you to link a Jenkins job to a git repository (included GitHub). Then use custom actions to run unit tests.